# How to stop camel route when there's no exchange for 10 mins

Tags: apache-camel

I think the title is quit clear.  Also for camelcontext, is there's a way to stop it if there's no active routes?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a MonitoringRoute for example which checks the other routes. For shutting down routes you can for example use the camel control bus, see: http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html